# Logstash Avro Codec Not Recognised

Tags: logstash, kafka-consumer-api

In the restricted network, I am unable to download `logstash-codec-avro` as we are unable to reach internet. Is there a packaged `logstash-codec-avro` that I could download and upload onto the network?

The following is the way I am planning on using:

```
input {
  kafka {
    codec => avro {
        schema_uri => "/tmp/schema.avsc"
    }
  }
}
```

However in the restricted machine, it says no codec named avro found. I am assuming after downloading / zip i will be able to decode the data incoming from kafka.

Comment: Try to generate an offline plugin package from an machine with internet access following this part of the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.9/offline-plugins.html). You should use the same logstash version that is installed in your restricted machine. Which version are you using? I think that from version 7.X the `avro` codec comes bundled with logstash.

Comment: @leandrojmp Thanks that worked. I have upgraded to 7.9 and able to use avro codec.